# Positive Count // Negative Sum

Tags: python, list-comprehension, multiple-variable-return

A fairly easy problem, but I'm still practicing iterating over multiple variables with for loops. In the below, I seek to return a new list, where x is the count of positive numbers and y is the sum of negative numbers from an input array `arr.`

If the input array is empty or null, I am to return an empty array.

Here's what I've got!

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    return [] if not arr else [(count(x), sum(y)) for x, y in arr]
```

Currently receiving...

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Besides the TypeError, I don't know where to insert the conditions of x being positive and y being negative.

Comment: Could you give an example of the arr?

Comment: @picmate arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]

Comment: You get the TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, because, y or x is a integer at a given moment. sum works on lists.

Comment: how would you revise what I wrote to reflect that?

Comment: It's rather difficult to revise your code there. Initially, you are trying to iterate arr with two variables, x and y; however, arr has only singular elements. Next, in list comprehension, the aim is to generate another list. And a function like sum only works on lists; so you could only use sum once you have created the list. You could do something like (sum([1 for x in arr if x > 0]), sum([x for x in arr if x < 0])), but again it is a one line version of @wim 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `sum` comprehension

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
>>> sum(1 for x in arr if x > 0)
10
>>> sum(x for x in arr if x < 0)
-65
```

Comment: but how do i return one new list with both variables accounted for?

Comment: Well, just assign them to local variables c,s then return [c,s]

Answer (score 1):

wim's way is good.  Numpy is good for these types of things too.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15])
print([arr[arr >= 0].size, arr[arr < 0].sum()])
>> [10, -65]
```

Answer (score 1):

the error you get is from this part `for x,y in arr` that mean that `arr` is expected to be a list of tuples of 2 elements (or any similar container), like for example this `[(1,2), (5,7), (7,9)]` but what you have is a list of numbers, which don't contain anything else inside...

Now to get your desire result you can use the solution of **wim**, which need to iterate over the list twice or you can get it in one go with

```
>>> def fun(iterable):
        if not iterable:
            return []
        pos = 0
        neg = 0
        for n in iterable:
            if n>=0:
                pos = pos + 1
            else:
                neg = neg + n
        return [pos, neg]

>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
>>> fun(arr)
[10, -65]
>>>
```

Comment: I like this a lot, thank you both! The one modification I made to accomodate other input tests was to change line 7 to > as it seems this problem is treating 0s as non-positives.